# Change datetime e.g. 01JAN2020:13:04:10.00000 in r

Tags: r, date, datetime, timestamp, posixct

*I haven't been able to find another question - but I feel like there is one out there, so sorry if I'm asking a duplicate question!*

I have a date time column in the following format (character):

```
date <- "02OCT2019:15:04:34.000000"
```

I've tried to convert the column to a date with

```
new_date <- as.POSIXct(date, "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S%OS")
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I feel like my problem lies in the month part because it's written in caps. I tried substringing just the date (%d%b%Y) and using as.POSIXct on that, getting the same error.

I don't know if it's relevant, but my locale is

```
Sys.getlocale()
[1]"LC_COLLATE=Danish_Denmark.1252;LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252;LC_MONETARY=Danish_Denmark.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Danish_Denmark.1252"
```

And the month format used is not Danish, but English (hence OCT, in Danish it would be OKT).

Hope some of you can help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)

date <- "02OCT2019:15:04:34.000000"

dmy_hms(date)

# [1] "2019-10-02 15:04:34 UTC"
```

Comment: Thanks! That was so simple. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

As Ritchie said in the comments. Naming the format does the trick. Furthermore you should change `%S%OS` to `%OS`. `%OS` already does the seconds and fraction, so `%S` is not needed.

All in all, the following should work `new_date <- as.POSIXct(date, format = "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%OS")`

Edit: This works for me with the following locale:

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=sv_SE.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=sv_SE.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=sv_SE.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=sv_SE.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
```

Comment: Thanks. It didn't work for those dates that are combined Danish and English, fx "02OCT2019:15:04:34.000000", but it did work for those that could be both Danish and English fx "23JUN2021:10:45:00.000000". But the lubridate solution suggested by Merijn worked. But I'll remember the %OS next time!

Comment: That will be likely due to your Locale settings. If you set that to US it should work. But good to hear that the lubridate solution solves your problem!